# Sending text on android phone commanded by Raspberry pi USB, WITHOUT internet

Tags: python, usb, android

I simply want the Raspberry Pi to instruct a mobile Android phone to send a text SMS.
The preferred connection to the Pi is via USB.
I **do not** have an internet connection in this configuration.
I have looked at Airdroid and Desksms but don't think these will work as I need the command to come from a Python script.
Is it possible?

Comment: I haven't used a phone's hotspot this way, but it should certainly be possible to contact the phone via the hotspot.   There's also bluetooth, which should give you better range but uses more power and requires a more expensive adapter on the pi.   Specific questions about Android programming are obviously off-topic here and belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).   Note this is very unlikely to be a get-it-done-on-the-weekend project if you are not satisfied with pre-existing solutions.

Comment: WRT a direct cable connection and python, you could look into whatever protocol the [adb shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) uses, but if you want to actually use it on the pi I believe you'll have to compile it yourself.